# WebClient UploadFile call fails only on MP4 files

Tags: c#, file-upload

So I have an application that uploads files to a server via POST and it uploads files of different types in the following sequence:

jpg->mp4->mp3

The jpg and mp3 uploads work just fine whereas the mp4 file upload fails with the following error:

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I'm wondering how/why this could happen when I'm using the same URL each time and the only thing that's changing here is the extension of the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change [maxAllowedContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  in your web.config to allow bigger file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not accepting the file.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a file size issue rather than an extension issue which makes more sense. Any ideas on how to address that? The web server is IIS 7.

Comment: An aspx page that takes some parameters on the query string and cycles through the posted files and saves them.